# In Flask, server gives the response of GET but I have requested for POST for creating the data

Tags: flask, post, get

So, in Flask, instead of doing POST request, I am getting the GET from the server.

```
  @app.route("/fbr", methods=['POST'])
  def nmp():
    
   //data comes her that needs to be generated-------

    response = request(method='POST',url = "https://example.com", 
    auth= (id, secret), data=data)
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4))
    a= response.json()["a"]
    b= response.json()["b"]
    print(a)
    print(b)
    c = a+ SPACE + b
    return c

 This is the error below.
"GET /fbr/ HTTP/1.1" 405"
```

Bit when I am doing the POST from  POSTMAN, I am getting my data. But from the server, this is not the case.

Any suggestions or clue where I am going wrong. And I have used here dummy variables here in the code but is exactly the same.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, your flask server has a route called `"/fbr"` and the method is `POST`.

According to your error, you are trying to send a `GET` request to your `POST` endpoint. So it's correct that you get `405` response.

Just change your endpoint's method to `GET`

```
  @app.route("/fbr", methods=['GET'])
```